# Check if byte sequence contains utf-16

Tags: string, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

I am reading a byte sequence from a stream.  Assume for the sake of argument, that the sequence is of a fixed length and I read the whole thing into a byte array (in my case it's `vector<char>` but it's not important for this question).  This byte sequence contains a string, which my be either in utf-16 or in utf-8 encoding.  Unfortunately, there's no indicator of which one it is.

I can verify whether the byte sequence represents a valid utf-16 encoding and also whether it represents a valid utf-8 encoding, but I can also imaging how the same sequence of bytes may be a valid utf-8 and a valid utf-16 at the same time.

So, does that mean there's no way to generically figure out which one it is?

Comment: Even the "best" sometimes make a mistake: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts

Comment: I'd love to know what the downvote was for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the contents are expected to be written in a language using the Latin script, simply counting nulls will detect UTF-16. In UTF-8, null bytes will decode to NUL control character, and they don't appear in text normally.

Languages written in other scripts cannot be fully valid in both UTF-16 and UTF-8 unless it's artificially constructed to be so.

So, first detect if it's fully valid UTF-8 sequence on its own:

- If yes, check for null bytes, and if there are some, it's UTF-16. Otherwise it's UTF-8.
- If not, it's UTF-16.

If the above resulted in UTF-16, that's not enough as you have to know the endianess as well. With languages written in Latin script, the amount of odd or even null bytes will tell this.

Comment: It's not latin script only - it can be any script in any language (including RTL)

Comment: @AleksG Sure, that wasn't a requirement. Just saying that if you expect the text to be legible in any kind of language, then what I say in my answer could actually work. It is only artificially constructed strings, not being legible in any language, that cannot be distinguished between UTF-8 and UTF-16.

Comment: "The Latin script" is rather ill-defined; if you mean Latin-1, that doesn't even include common characters like the en-dash, `–`.

Comment: @larsmans I mean Latin script languages such as English, Finnish, German, Icelandic etc. They are bound to have null bytes when encoded as UTF-16 because they use mainly the first 256 characters, Basic and Supplemental Latin. I don't mean the encoding ISO-8859-1 at all.

Answer (score 2):

> So, does that mean there's no way to generically figure out which one it is?

That's right. The byte string `[0x30, 0x30]` can be the UTF-8 string `00` or the UTF-16 encoding of the character `〰`. That's a WAVY DASH, in case you were wondering.

There are a few more heuristics to try:

- You can check whether the string begins with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (Windows programs love those), since neither BOM is a valid start of a UTF-8 sequence.
- If you're sure there are no NUL characters in the string, then every even-length string containing zero bytes must be UTF-16.

If those fail, you'll have to default to either one of the options, or do some kind of check on the contents of the string when decoded with both -8 and -16.

Comment: The majority of UTF-16 strings are not valid UTF-8. Depending on what sort of input you are expecting, a usable heuristic might be to default to UTF-8 but fall back to UTF-16 (but which kind?) if you see invalid sequences. If every other byte is a constant, or from a constrained repertoire of just a few constants, that might be a useful observation as well (zero bytes are technically valid UTF-8 but if every second byte is a zero, that's a strong UTF-16 hint).

Comment: @triplee Unfortunately, there's no control over what that string can be.  All I know is that it's a text string, which can be in *any* language in *any* script (including RTL ones).

Comment: That doesn't really affect the heuristics above, but if the input can be just a few bytes, there is very little to go on.

Comment: @tripleee: true. I consider "that's right" to be the main part of the answer :)